# ScrollRect interferes with dragobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm implementing a drag script on my gameobjects so the user can rotate them by touching the screen, I also have a horizontal scrollrect wich contains the buttons the user can choose to show the respective object, what is happening is when the user slide the finger to rotate the object the scrollrect is scrolling together, how can I prevent the scrollrect scroll when I rotate the object?

DragObject:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class DragObject : MonoBehaviour {
    private float m_RotationSpeed = 40f;
    void Start () {
    }

    void Update() {

        if (1 == Input.touchCount) {

            gameObject.transform.Rotate (Vector3.down, Input.touches [0].deltaPosition.x * m_RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            }
        }
}
```

ScrollRect:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the interfaces in UnityEngine.EventSystems insted of using Update method.

That way the event is used and your scroll rect doesn't move.

If you haven't used it before follow these steps:

1. Create an empty GameObject inside your Canvas that fills the
   space where your user should make the gestures.
2. Create a new script that inherits from [UnityEngine.UI.Graphic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html) (or add a graphic component to it like an `Image` or `Text`, in that case inherit from `Monobehaviour` as usual) and uses the interfaces that you are interested in, In your case I think they are, [IBeginDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IBeginDragHandler.html), [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IBeginDragHandler.html) and [IEndDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html)

An example of a script could be this

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class EventsExample : Graphic, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

    public GameObject movingObject; // I AM ROTATIN IF YOU DRAG!!

    private float m_RotationSpeed = 1f;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("START DRAGGING, I ONLY GET CALLED ONCE PER FINGER");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("I AM DRAGGING AND I AM GETTING CALLED EACH FRAME PER FINGER");
        movingObject.transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, eventData.delta.x * m_RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("I END DRAGGING AND I AM GETTING CALLED ONCE PER FINGER");
    }
}
```

3. Add this script to the empty GameObject you created inside your Canvas, if you inherited from Monobehaviour then you should add also a Graphic Component like an Image or Text.
4. If you want the user to be able to drag to rotate in the whole screen but the scrollrect, then make the empty gameobject fill all your canvas and set it as the first child of your canvas,then put below the `ScrollRect`. In Unity UI, the last child of the canvas is the object that is on top of it, so this way your `ScrollRect` will be Above your empty GameObject and will catch the drag event when dragging over it.
5. That should do it, if you are copy pasting my script, be sure to set the movingObject variable to the object you want to rotate.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it is working fine now, but the console is showing an error: NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
EventDrag.OnEndDrag (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at Assets/EventDrag.cs:31) Should I ignore that?

Comment: That's because you deleted the onenddrag function and didn't delete the IEndDragHandler